# Ring on silent mode

Tags: android

I am writing an app which will ring on silent mode for certain numbers. I've created a broadcast listener which will listen to the incoming call and ring for a specific number.  The problem I'm facing is for the first time after installation it's not working and after that it's working perfectly.

The code I'm using is

```
    public class Ring extends BroadcastReceiver{
private Context context;
private String PhoneNumber;
private int ringerMode=0;
String state=null;
Bundle bundle=null;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 AudioManager maudio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  bundle = intent.getExtras();
  this.context = context;

  if(null == bundle)
          return;

  state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

  if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
  {
          check();
          PhoneNumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
          if(PhoneNumber.equals("+918281306132"))
          makeitNormal();
          maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
  }
  if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
  {
      makeItSilent();
  }

  if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
  {
      makeItSilent();
  }
}

private void check() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  AudioManager maudio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  ringerMode=maudio.getRingerMode();

}

 private void makeitNormal() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   AudioManager maudio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
 }


 private void makeItSilent() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 AudioManager maudio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  int ringer=maudio.getRingerMode();
  if (ringerMode==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT){

  maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

  }else if(ringerMode==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL){
  maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
 }
 else if(ringerMode==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE){
  maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
 }

 }

 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

}
  }

Comment: This seems to go against the expected user functionality.  Surely if your phone is on silent, you don't want it to ring?

Comment: Actually i want to ring it for certain number only so i just tried with one number.

Comment: @david99world I don't see it as a bad idea. Imagine you want it to be silent, except for your girlfriend/parents/whatever. There are always exceptional cases you may want to keep an eye (or an ear) on.

Comment: yep,So whats the trouble with my code i am not able to find.pls help me...

Comment: Ah - sorry I didn't realize the functionality was for a specific number.  I initially read it as "ring when on silent" which seemed to go against the user expectation.  I've edited the question so it's more obvious this is the scenario.

Comment: ok...now over to the real problem..

Comment: @ammukuttylive : what is the status of Device when u are installing app first time ? i mean NORMAL, SILENT OR VIBRATE ?

Answer (score 0):

The only thought came to my mind is to call the `check()` method outside the `onReceive()`, to set `ringerMode` filed before `onRecieve()` is trigerred.

Comment: then how OP access context outside onRecieve() to get AUDIO_SERVICE?